# Wii U connected to projector audio issues

Tags: audio-hardware, wii-u

I'm thinking of buying a Wii U but It seems that it doesn't have an audio out (only HDMI). My projector Sanyo Z-700 has HDMI but I can't get sound out of my projector.

So is there any tested way to get sound out of the HDMI through some adapter that works with the Wii U?

Comment: Simply google your question? http://www.giantbomb.com/wii-u/3045-139/forums/why-is-audio-output-restricted-to-hdmi-only-567724/

Comment: Sounds like you need something along the lines of an HDMI splitter or something.  Do they even make something like that?

Comment: @fbueckert there exists some HDMI splitters but I was hoping someone could give me thumbs-up that it works together with the Wii U because I don't want to waste some 30$ for something that doesn't work.

Comment: There are also these things called HD receivers that are designed for managing all your entertainment centre's inputs and outputs.

Comment: I don't see how the Wii U would be special in any regard like that; HDMI is an international standard.  A fast Wikipedia search confirms this.  If anything, talking to your local Best Buy/Future Shop dude and asking if you can test it before you buy it is probably a valid request.

Answer (score 1):

Wii U have build in component/composite output, which you can use for audio output. I don't know however if analog cables comes in package, but [you certainly can buy it separately](http://hyperkin.com/nintendo-wii/wii-cables/nintendo-wii-component-cable.html). The problem is you can't use both HDMI and analog for output (HDMI is turned off if analog is used and vice versa). You option is to use component output and connect audio cable to whatever you want.